# Converting c structure with union to Delphi record

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, structure

I'm wondering if this c structure I've translated to Delphi is incorrect, and if incorrect, how it can be translated properly? Since the union is mid structure it seems it's not as simple to convert this properly. Any help would be much appreciated

```cpp
typedef struct FWPM_FILTER0_ {
    GUID                   filterKey;
    FWPM_DISPLAY_DATA0     displayData;
    UINT32                 flags;
    GUID                   *providerKey;
    FWP_BYTE_BLOB          providerData;
    GUID                   layerKey;
    GUID                   subLayerKey;
    FWP_VALUE0             weight;
    UINT32                 numFilterConditions;
    FWPM_FILTER_CONDITION0 *filterCondition;
    FWPM_ACTION0           action;
    union {
        UINT64 rawContext;
        GUID   providerContextKey;
    };
    GUID                   *reserved;
    UINT64                 filterId;
    FWP_VALUE0             effectiveWeight;
} FWPM_FILTER0;
```

```pascal
type
  FWPM_FILTER0 = record
    filterKey: TGUID;
    displayData: FWPM_DISPLAY_DATA0;
    flags: UINT32;
    providerKey: PGUID;
    providerData: FWP_BYTE_BLOB;
    layerKey: TGUID;
    subLayerKey: TGUID;
    weight: FWP_VALUE0;
    numFilterConditions: UINT32;
    filterCondition: PFWPM_FILTER_CONDITION0;
    action: FWPM_ACTION0;
    case Integer of
      0: (rawContext: UINT64);
      1: (providerContextKey: TGUID;
    reserved: PGUID;
    filterId: UINT64;
    effectiveWeight: FWP_VALUE0);
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant part of a record has to appear at the end of a record, in Delphi. Because this union appears in the middle of the struct, you will need to declare the union as a separate type in Delphi and then use it in the containing record.

Comment: I see. Oddly enough my translated structure compiled and shows the same sizeof as the c struct, but it didn't look correct to me. Would this be the equivalent (without explicitly declaring a new type)?

Comment: type FWPM_FILTER0 = record
    filterKey: TGUID;
    displayData: FWPM_DISPLAY_DATA0;
    flags: UINT32;
    providerKey: PGUID;
    providerData: FWP_BYTE_BLOB;
    layerKey: TGUID;
    subLayerKey: TGUID;
    weight: FWP_VALUE0;
    numFilterConditions: UINT32;
    filterCondition: PFWPM_FILTER_CONDITION0;
    action: FWPM_ACTION0;
    union: record
    case Integer of
    0: (rawContext: UINT64);
    1: (providerContextKey: TGUID);
    end;
    reserved: PGUID;
    filterId: UINT64;
    effectiveWeight: FWP_VALUE0;
end;

Comment: That will have the desired layout but the semantics are wrong. The fields following the union are always present. But in your version, semantically, they may not be. Do it the way I said. It's much better that way anyway.

Comment: Like this?

type TUnion = record
case Integer of
    0: (rawContext: UINT64);
    1: (providerContextKey: TGUID);
end;

type FWPM_FILTER0 = record
    filterKey: TGUID;
    displayData: FWPM_DISPLAY_DATA0;
    flags: UINT32;
    providerKey: PGUID;
    providerData: FWP_BYTE_BLOB;
    layerKey: TGUID;
    subLayerKey: TGUID;
    weight: FWP_VALUE0;
    numFilterConditions: UINT32;
    filterCondition: PFWPM_FILTER_CONDITION0;
    action: FWPM_ACTION0;
    union: TUnion;
    reserved: PGUID;
    filterId: UINT64;
    effectiveWeight: FWP_VALUE0;
end;

Answer (score 1):

Just fold the fields after the CASE block into one of the branches (preferably the largest one)

Declaring a separate record would require changing the way you access it.

P.s. not entirely mine, see Rudy Velthuis' site, http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html

Comment: In this case it is fine but there are situations where alignment will be incorrect if you do that.