# Delphi Convert C struct that have nested union and struct with no (variant record Flags)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How do I convert this type of struct, with a nested union and struct inside of it?

Example C:

```
struct pjsip_cred_info
{
    pj_str_t    realm;      
    pj_str_t    scheme;     
    pj_str_t    username;   
    int     data_type;  
    pj_str_t    data;       
    union {
            struct {
                     pj_str_t     k;    
                     pj_str_t     op;   
                     pj_str_t     amf;  
                     pjsip_cred_cb cb;  
            } aka;
    } ext;
};
```

and what variable type for "case varType of ".
here my example :

```
pjsip_cred_info = record
    realm     : pj_str_t;
    scheme    : pj_str_t;
    username  : pj_str_t;
    data_type : Integer;
    data      : pj_str_t;
    aka : record
        k,op,amf : pj_str_t;
        cb : pjsip_cred_cb;   // pointer type
    end;
  end;
```

the example delphi code above is correct?

Comment: Can we get the code for the missing structs?

Comment: The union only has one element so you don't need a variant record

Comment: Mr. @R.J. Dunnill aka struct?.

Comment: Mr. @David Heffernan in case we can define new struct inside?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56906440

Comment: Yes you can embed a record inside another

Comment: Mr. Tom Brunberg what flag must i use for variant record.

Comment: You don't need a variant record. Still. If you want to translate this you need to understand how the C struct is laid out. Do you?

Comment: ok, Mr. David. I don't really understand the "C" language in building structs that are nested and how c allocated memory for that..

Comment: Well, how can you expect to translate that which you don't understand. Its not too hard to understand, but you will need to do a little research.

Comment: NativeInt is wrong. Should be Integer.